# Android Studio xml design doesn't show anything, only a rect. and no error ,no issues

Tags: android, android-studio

Toady, I found my AS xml design not worked. It doesn't show anything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUWBu.png)

And this project can build successfully, install apk also successfully, gradle sync,clean porject and rebuild project also successfully too. But the design widow doesn't show anything, I have tried change theme in style.xml, change theme in AS settings, uninstall AS, reinstanll AS(3.6.3, 2020.3.1Fox, 2021.3.1), but not resolve this problem。I've tried everything I can think of。
And i found a difference on AS 3.6.3， on this idea, the project also can run, gradle sync successfully, but design window always show “waiting for build finish”， but this project already build successfully。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/divi0.png)

Can anyone help me? Thank you very munch。

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio makes a lot of files like caches and does not delete them. This can cause a problem when there is a need to make new files, so clearing caches will clear the old cache and make Android Studio faster. So to Invalidate caches/ Restart, go to the file which is present in the top menu bar in Android Studio and then click on the option “Invalidate Caches/Restart…” present in the Dropdown. After that it will ask you that “Would you like to continue?”, click on Invalidate and Restart button. Below are the links from geeksforgeeks
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/

Comment: First,Thanks a lot, and I had tried the solution by you, but it doesn't work. and I also had tried the others from geeksforgeeks.org, but doesn't work too.  But， Thank you anyway。